How can I implement a barcode scanner in browser using nextjs (ts)?
the idea is that the browser should ask for permission for video camera, and i can scan the browser, (I'm using typescript)
I tried dynamsoft-camera-enhancer, but there is a problem with dynamsoft-camera-enhancer/dist/types/interface/playcallbackinfo,
I tries react-qr-reader, but it's not supported by next.
